# Writing integer values to a file in binary using C

Tags: c, io, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, fwrite

I am trying to write 9 bit numbers to a binary file.

For example, i want to write the integer value: 275 as `100010011` and so on. `fwrite` only allows one byte to be written at a time and I am not sure how to manipulate the bits to be able to do this.

Comment: See also [Writing a stream of 9-bit values as bytes to a file in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47505922/writing-a-stream-of-9-bit-values-as-bytes-to-a-file-in-c) — a successor question by the same OP also about 9-bit values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a minimum of two bytes to store a 9-bits value. An easy solution is to use 16 bits per 9 bits value

Choose a 16 bits unsigned type, eg `uint16_t` and store the 2 bytes

```
 uint16_t w = 275;
 fwrite(&w, 1, 2, myfilep);
```

Reading the word `w`, ensure it actually uses only its 9 first bits (bits 0~8)

```
 w &= 0x1FF;
```

Note that you might have endianness issues if you read the file on another system that doesn't have the same endianness as the system that *wrote* the word.

You could also optimize that solution using 9 bits of a 16 bits word, then using the remaining 7 bits to store the first 7 bits of the next 9 bits value etc...

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work) that explains how to work with bit shifting in C.