# Writing a stream of 9 bit values as bytes to a file in C

Tags: c, io, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, fwrite

I have an array with integer values from 0-511 (9 bits max). I am trying to write this to a file with `fwrite`.

For Example, with the array:

```
[257, 258, 259]
Which is 100000001, 100000010, 100000011

I am trying to write
100000001100000010100000011 + extra padding of 0s to the file
```

But since fwrite limits writes to 1 byte at a time, I am not sure how to go about doing this. I am new to bitwise operations and am not how to separate out the individual bytes.

Comment: Closely related to [Writing integer values to a file in binary using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504816/writing-integer-values-to-a-file-in-binary-using-c) — by the same OP and also about 9-bit values.

Comment: Unless you're on some extremely unusual hardware, there are no 9-bit data types available.  You have to store each "9-bit" value in a 16-bit datum in memory and on disk.  You could in theory store 3 x 9-bit values in a single 32-bit unit, I suppose.  At the moment, it is not clear what you're after or why.  If you're working on 36-bit hardware, do say so; the rules suddenly change.  There used to be such machines; I don't think there are many still running, but you could be about to educate me.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The previous Q was more general, in this one OP asks specifically a method/algo to optimally write n x 9-bits into (n x 9)/8+1 bytes. If a solution is released, we could then stuff it into the previous Q.

Comment: @RingØ: I marvel at your reading that from the question.  I don't get that message, but I'm not particularly worried about that.  I think clarification is in order, though.  You have to know how the data was written to be able to retrieve it.  I don't think you could write 1 unit, then 3 units, then 2 units, then 1 unit to disk and reliably read them in again unless you knew that was the sequence in which they were written.  But I could be missing everything.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler from both questions actually ;-) [didn't have the courage to write the bit-shifting stuff into the previous Q, and well, could be hidden somewhere else on SO...] (+another warning about endianness...)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am trying to implement an LZW compression algorithm. I have unsigned int values that range from 257-512 that I need to write to a file. Since these values are 9 bits, I am trying to pack them into 8 bits and read from them later.

Comment: If the values range from 257-512, simply subtract 257 from the value and save the 8-bit quantity (0..255).  That will save you endless headaches.  On reading, add 257 back again.  You'd have 16-bit quantities that you'd map to a sequence of 8-bit values, and you'd read an array of 8-bit values and expand them back into 16-bit quantities.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That could work. Sadly I need to pack the bits as this is for a school project.

Comment: Have fun.  I don't think even sadistic teachers would try to make you work with 9-bit data storage.  It simply doesn't work sanely in a powers-of-2 world of computing sizes.

Comment: The logical choise should be to write 16 bits integer. But if you need to save space it could be intersting understand how to "compress" this kind of data!

Comment: Your question would be more interesting if you'd elaborate on the *why* (in the question). A typical approach for data like that would be to pad the data to a multiple of 8 9bit-words and then write 8 times 8 bits, followed by an octet of most-significant bits. Even simpler and probably not worse in space efficiancy: just use 16bit words and a generic compression algorithm.

Comment: Incidentally, you should check your range.  512 needs a tenth bit; it isn't a 9-bit value.  Did you mean 256..511?  It doesn't affect the add/subtract 257 scheme; it might affect processing elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a bit buffer.

Since you are writing 8 bits at the time, you must
have data type that can hold at least 9+7 bits at minimum. `uint16_t` would do,
but I recommend using size that would at least as big as your native `int`. Make sure you use unsigned types to avoid shifting issues.

```
uint32_t bitBuffer = 0;  // Our temporary bit storage
uint32_t count = 0;      // Number of bits in buffer
```

Let's assume we have single data:

```
uint32_t data9b = 257;  // 1 0000 0001
```

Adding bits to buffer is simple; just shift bits at the end of the buffer, 
and combine with OR.

```
bitBuffer |= (data9b << count); // At first iteration, shift does nothing
count += 9;                     // Update counter
```

After 9 bits are added, we can flush 8 bits to file.

```
while(count >= 8) {
    writeToFile(bitBuffer & 0xFF);  // Mask out lowest bits with AND
    bitBuffer >>= 8;                // Remove written bits
    count -= 8;                     // Fix counter
}
```

After each cycle you have 0 - 7 bits left over in the buffer. At the end of all data, if you finish with non-multiple of 8 bits, just write remaining contents of `bitBuffer` to file.

```
if(count > 0)
    writeToFile(bitBuffer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so did it using bit shifting, oring (can also do with `*`, '+', `%` and `/`) but shift is more appropriate / readable, imo.

```
// Your data, n is the number of 9-bits values
uint16_t dat[] = { 257, 258, 259 };
int i,n = sizeof(dat)/sizeof(*dat);

// out file
FILE *fp = fopen("f8.bin","w");

uint16_t one = 0;
int shift = 0;
uint8_t b;

// main loop
for(i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
    b = (dat[i] << shift) | one; // one is remainder from previous value
    one = dat[i]>>(8-shift);     // Move the remaining MSb to the right
    shift = (shift+9) % 8;       // next shift
    fwrite(&b, 1, 1, fp);        // write our b byte
}
// remainder, always have a remainder
fwrite(&one, 1, 1, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

Had fun :-)